# Is there a name for points of a metric space which are limits of sequences in a subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, terminology

Suppose $X$ is a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. By definition, $x \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if every punctured ball centered at $x$, $B_r(x) - \{x\}$, contains a point of $A$. This definition means that some points of $A$ may not be limit points of $A$; for example, if $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $A = \{0\} \cup [1, 2]$, then $0$ is not a limit point of $A$.

My question is if we remove the "punctured" condition in the definition, what are the resulting points called? In other words, I am looking for the name of a point which is the limit of $any$ sequence in $A$, including the constant ones.

Thanks.

Comment: The set of all such points is the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of $A$.

Comment: I’d just call it an element of the closure of $A$, but the term [*adherent point*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point) is used.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ovi: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then this called an [adherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point) point (etymologically this means a "sticky" point) of $A$. The set of all these points turns out to be exactly the closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$.

Comment: Thank you! ${}$